# Execute a migration from a composer package install

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

So we're trying to create a service for our project, but want to put it in package that we can use in other projects. There would be a couple migrations in this package, so I'm wondering what the process would be for housing the migration in the composer package and running it on install.

My thoughts would be to have composer run the artisan command to create a migration with a set name and then copy the migration in the package over the one created, and then running the artisan migrate command.

Is this solution good, or are there better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a package laravel, the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages) gives you the opportunity to add migration from your package by adding this in your package ServiceProvider

```
/**
 * src/NameAuthor/NamePackage/ServiceProvider.php
 * migrations package inside src/database/migrations folder by example
 *
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/database/migrations/' => database_path('migrations')
    ], 'migrations');
}
```

Then you can run the command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=migrations
```

If you wish to launch directly migrations with composer, you can add key "scripts" in composer.json, and just launch composer. [The documentation of composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) about this is more clear, but this is an example of laravel composer.json of laravel

```
"scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
```

Then you can inject yourself the command above if you want to launch composer and retrieve package migrations.